# Teradata JDBC connection speed depends on connection string. Why?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

So I've written a basic java code to connect to Teradata. The connection used to be slow when I used the following connection string.

`jdbc:teradata://DB1/TMODE=ANS,CHARSET=UTF8,LOGMECH=TD2`

Now I've changed to the following,

`jdbc:teradata://DB1.yyy.zzz/LOGMECH=TD2` and the connection has become faster. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: How do you know the connection is faster? If it is, how do you know something else has not changed?

Comment: When *connection speed* means *time to establish a connection, i.e. logon* and `DB1.yyy.zzz` is faster, then the delay was caused by network name resolution.

Comment: This could be by chance.. there is no way that connection string fastens your DB response... between how did you measure the DB response time

Comment: I wrote a loop that created a connection and closed it. I averaged the time taken. @PavanKumarK Like you said, sometimes, they are the same. But quite a few times, I've seen that the second connection is faster. This doesn't happen with the first string. Maybe, it's just chance. But how can I test this?

Comment: @dnoeth I also thought the same. Maybe the name resolution for `DB1.yyy.zzz` is faster. How do I make sure that it is indeed the problem?

Comment: @ak31: It depends on the actual name resolution within your network. Try `nslookup DB1` vs. `DB1.yyy.zzz`

Comment: just measure how long it takes to simply open the connection before the first call. When I use COPS vs direct name, the difference is distinct on my end, for instance.

Comment: the first string takes around 40 seconds, while the second one takes only 2 seconds!